# How to redirect user to a different path on the same domain with a click of a button in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am creating a simple web app, and I want to be able to redirect a user to a different path in my project with a click of a button. I have two same versions of the website in english and polish. I am using express in node js and dynamic routing. And at the moment when I click the button it just adds the path on top of already existing path leading to nowhere. Forgive me if it's a rookie problem, I can't seem to figure out why it is happening.

My code in backend looks like this:

```
app.get("/stand/:lang/:id", function(req, res){

  const requestedLang = req.params.lang;
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
  if (requestedLang === 'en' && requestedId === "1"){
    res.render("stand1en");
  } else if (requestedLang === 'pl' && requestedId === "1") {
    res.render("stand1");
  }
});
```

My front end and the buttons looks like this:

```
<a href="/stand/pl/1" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 button-polish">Polski</a>
      <a href="/stand/en/1" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 button-english">English</a>
```

I would like to redirect them to the website on a click of the button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.redirect) in node.

You need to have 2 route :

1 that render the

> "en" file

and 1 that render

> "pl" file

Answer (score 0):

You can use res.redirect function of expressjs which redirects to the URL derived from the specified path.

```
app.get("/stand/:lang/:id", function(req, res){

 const requestedLang = req.params.lang;
 const requestedId = req.params.id;
 if (requestedLang === 'en' && requestedId === "1"){
    res.redirect("link to the page1!");
 } else if (requestedLang === 'pl' && requestedId === "1") {
    res.redirect("link to the page2");
 }

});
```

I think this will solve your problem.